# How do I intuitively draw phase portrait from pseudopotential vs $x$ plot?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, potential-energy, phase-space

I am struggling with the process of deducing a phase portrait from pseudopotential vs $x$ plot. Is there a resource that would be helpful in understanding it better?

Given the pseudopotential(V) vs $x$ in the figure:

[image: V vs x]

For different energy levels E(y= -4) = E1; E(y=0) = E2; E(y=4) = E3

I there a way to plot the phase portrait $\dot{x}$ vs $x$?

Comment: the kinetic energy goes as velocity squared, so think about drawing the lines of equipotential for a 3d graph which is something like z = y^2 + x^3

Comment: More specifically, on a graph with axes $x$ and $\dot x$, graph $m \dot x^2 / 2 + k x^3 = const$ for different constants.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some python code for generating phase planes

[image]